# Is it possible to detect when a user is moving to next/previous slide in presenting mode in Office PowerPoint API?

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I’m using the PowerPoint API v1.4 to build a custom add-in for PowerPoint.
Problem is that I haven’t found a way to detect when a user moves forward or backward between the slides while in presenting mode.

E.g. an event to listen to that would be something like willMoveToNextSlide/didMoveToNextSlide (and same with previous), or an event that tells me slideDidChange/Move, returning the index of the new slide, or something like that.

Just something to tell me that the user moved in either direction away from the current slide in presenting mode.

Is there a well hidden solution to this?

Comment: If a JS add-in can trap/respond to PowerPoint's events, this may help: http://youpresent.co.uk/powerpoint-application-events-in-vba/  
You likely want to use OnSlideShowPageChange

Comment: OnSlideShowPageChange is for the vba add-in and only supported by powerpoint on windows, and not in the Office API if I understand correct, even if it would be helpful also in the API. We are using the API to support both Windows, Mac and Web, but the API is quite limited atm.

Comment: Thanks for the add'l information. That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

As Rick already mentioned, OfficeJS doesn't provide anything for that.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Answer (score -1):

PowerPoint add-ins do not work in Presentation mode.

If you can implement your scenario in editing mode, consider handling the [selection changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/read-and-write-data-to-the-active-selection-in-a-document-or-spreadsheet#detect-changes-in-the-selection) event.

Comment: Macros work in Presentation Mode. I don't know if that helps you with your use case. Perhaps - if you invoke the macro and that in turn moves to the next slide. (I have a macro on a button on the first slide to remove the first slide - and it ONLY works in Presentation Mode.)

Comment: The javascript is still running for the add-ins in presentation mode, even if you can not manipulate anything outside your content add-in, you still can run things in the add-in. From what I have experienced, you can not sync the context when in presentation mode, but you still can run your code while presenting.

Comment: @user20000939 There's some kind of terminological confusion here. The poster has tagged the question `office-js`, so this is an Office Web Add-in. These do not work in Presentation mode. In fact, the task pane isn't even visible when the deck is being presented.